# Is this proof about set product correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that if $A\times B=A\times C$ and $A\neq \emptyset$, then $B=C$.

Proof:
if$$(a,h)\in A\times B \Leftrightarrow (a,h)\in A\times C$$
So we note that WLOG that if $h\in B$ then $h\in C$

Comment: See [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36604/how-constructive-is-doyle-conways-division-by-three).

Comment: Probably better writing in this way: If $a\in A$, then $h\in B \Leftrightarrow (a,h)\in A\times B \Leftrightarrow (a,h)\in A\times C\Leftrightarrow h\in C$.

Answer (score 1):

It’s right, but it’s not stated very clearly. It would be clearer with a little more connective tissue to show the logic, something like this:

> Fix $a\in A$. Then for each $b\in B$ we have $\langle a,b\rangle\in A\times B=A\times C$, so $b\in C$, and hence $B\subseteq C$. By symmetry $C\subseteq B$, and hence $B=C$.